# Sort array by object key order with jQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, object

```
var ops = 
{
    '1':'Label 1',
    '2':'Label 2',
    '3':'Label 3',
};
var selected = ['3','1'];
var labels = selected.map(function(index)
{
    return ops[index];
});    
console.log(labels);
```

Returns: `(2) ["Label 3", "Label 1"]`

I'd like to return the labels in the order they appear in the `ops` object which has string keys. And I'm hoping to do it with brevity, preferably by chaining onto the `map` function, or even inside the same `map` function, if possible.

I've found several methods for sorting an `array` by another `array`, but nothing quick for sorting an `array` by `object` key order.

By all possible means I'd like to avoid an `each` function.

Comment: Objects are unordered. You need to use array if you want to maintain order

Comment: Array of objects is safest way to guarantee order `[{key:'1',label:'Label 1'}, {key:'2',label:'Label 2'}]`

Comment: Or use Map object if not needing to support older browsers

Comment: It's for iOS and Android on Cordova. How would I do that?

Comment: I might need to do an array of objects though. You're probably right. That means getting the label based on key value is going to be more work. :(

Comment: Could use both array and object, one for easy lookup, the other for ordering although looking up label by key in array is not difficult

Comment: @charlietfl with your guidance I came to this solution: https://jsfiddle.net/som34q0a/

That the simplest method, you think?

Comment: Far better than any of the answers below which are all flaky

Comment: Simpler approach... filter `ops` then map labels https://jsfiddle.net/som34q0a/3/. No sorting needed since working from ordered array

Comment: Brilliant. Make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array of items and filter that array based on selected array then map filtered array to labels.

Since you are working from ordered array there is no other sorting required

```js
var ops = 
[
    {value:'3',label:'Label 3'},
    {value:'1',label:'Label 1'},
    {value:'2',label:'Label 2'},
];
var selected = ['1','3'];

var labels = ops.filter(function(item){
   return selected.indexOf(item.value)>-1;
}).map(function(item){
   return item.label;
});

console.log(labels);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sort` function and its `predicate` or compare function.

```js
var ops = 
{
    '3':'Label 3',
    '1':'Label 1',
    '2':'Label 2',
    
};
var opsMap = ['3', '1', '2'];
var selected = ['3','1'];
var labels = selected.sort(function(a, b){
  
  if (opsMap.indexOf(a) < opsMap.indexOf(b)){
    return -1;
    
  }
  
  if (opsMap .indexOf(a) > opsMap .indexOf(b))
    return 1;
  
  return 0;
}).map(function(index)
{
    return ops[index];
});    
console.log(labels);
```

Looking further to the way JavaScript handles the object properties. I find out that it doesn't matter in which order you add your properties. JavaScript or its engine (whether it's V8, Chakra or anything else) the properties will be ordered in a certain way. You can learn further about it here:
http://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html
https://hackernoon.com/out-of-order-keys-in-es6-objects-d5cede7dc92e

But you can use a workaround by providing a map with the object like in this case: `let map = ['3', '1', '2']`. Then this map can be used later to get the elements in the right order using the described method above or other.

Further information on the `Map()` function in `ES6` and how to implement it in older browsers.

http://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/map-to-the-rescue-adding-order-to-object-properties/

Comment: This does not do what OP asked

Comment: That only works if the ops keys are in numerical order, which they generally won't be. Hence string keys.

Comment: @Thom Yes, and he can use the predicate or compare function to force his sorting policies if the indexes change

Comment: If there is a specific example, post it and I will handle it using the `sort` function.

Comment: Simply move `'3':'Label 3'` up into the first position of the `ops` properties and run your code again.

Comment: That certainly does what I asked. Well done and thanks.

Comment: I'm really not sure it does... if you change selected to ['1','2','3'], it comes out with Array [ "Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3" ]

Comment: `keys[a]`  and `keys[b]` are undefined. This code is nothing but smoke and mirrors

Comment: The problem here is with the 'keys' function - @mohessaid has assumed that they return the keys in their original order, which they don't.

var ops = 
{
    '3':'Label 3',
    '1':'Label 1',
    '2':'Label 2',
};

var keys = Object.keys(ops);
console.log(keys);

returns Array [ "1", "2", "3" ]

Comment: Yeah, but the console.log(labels) spits them out in the desired order. I don't understand where the magic is happening.

Comment: Seems like the object keys are ordered by the compiler when you retrieve them, hence the code won't work with normal keys. I will try to alter the solution to work with all cases.

Answer (score -1):

As @charlietfl say: there a no order inside a Object. But you could create an array containing all keys and sort this array. Then you loop over this array and fetch the values in that order.

```
var keys = new Array();
for(var key in ops){
  keys.push(key);
}
keys = keys.sort();
for(var key in keys){
  console.log(key+': '+ops[key]);
}
```

Comment: 0: undefined
1: Label 1
2: Label 2

Comment: @Marcus `keys` is an array, so you should use the `for...of` instead of the `for...in`.